# Wordpress Shop And Blog

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress shop plugins also blog pages but right now I want to make a new wordpress site and in this site I only want to show wordpress blog but it show blank page.I think because of plugins missing in new installation.One thing more I m using same database for both wordpress site.
Can any one please guide me?

Comment: So whats you problem?

Comment: Actually I want to integrate same blog with Magento the issue is that when I connect the database for fresh wordpress blog it show blank screen because shop plugins is missing in fresh copy I dont want to install any plugin in fresh wordpress copy.

Comment: What shop plugins you are talking about and also are you using Wordpress for blog purpose only with Magento?

Comment: No right now its separate website with Woocommerce wordpress plugin.I want to integrate that wordpress blog with magento.

Comment: Set `WP_DEBUG` to `TRUE` in `wp-config.php` file, it will show errors instead of blank screen.

Comment: Yes I tried but nothing show it show white blank page I also add php error reporting on but same issue.

Comment: How you pointing your blog with url like `http://magentoexample.com/blog`?

Comment: Its done but right now I just copy Wp_post data in new installation.Client is very happy because it integrate with theme.But I m not satisfied with this solution. Because semi integrate they need to post same post in 2 blogs.

Comment: Look i'm not really understand the point what `WP_Post` data?

Comment: Copy table of Wp_post from client old website and add the data in fresh installation of wordpress.And integrate that fresh WordPress with client magento website.

Comment: Thats not good wp_post is not only the post data table their is `wp_postmeta` also their terms `term_taxonomy`, `term_relationships` etc.

Comment: Yes I know but I don't want that solution I want to integrate the old database with fresh code.